# i finished making a game in Pygame and i got a invalid syntax error when i ran it

Tags: pygame

I just finished making a game in pygame and i got an invalid syntax error, any help?

```
import pygame

import random

pygame.font.init()

NP = false

MP = false

Font = pygame.font.SysFont("", 100)

Font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("", 300)

Font3 = pygame.font.SysFont("",55)

ann = font2.render("Press space to start", 1,  (255, 255, 255)

NPFont1 = Font3.render ("Normal", 1,  (0,0,0)

NPFont2 = Font3.render ("Play", 1,  (0,0,0)

NPFont1 = Font3.render ("Single", 1,  (0,0,0)

NPFont2 = Font3.render ("Play", 1,  (0,0,0)
```

Comment: You are missing numerous closing parentheses `)`. Also, `'false' != 'False'`.

Answer (score 0):

Missing many brackets.

```
ann = font2.render("Press space to start", 1,  (255, 255, 255))

NPFont1 = Font3.render ("Normal", 1,  (0,0,0))

NPFont2 = Font3.render ("Play", 1,  (0,0,0))

NPFont1 = Font3.render ("Single", 1,  (0,0,0))

NPFont2 = Font3.render ("Play", 1,  (0,0,0))
```